# undefined reference to `MX_USART2_UART_Init'

Tags: c, stm32, microcontroller

I get an error of undefined reference to `MX_USART2_UART_Init'

this is my main code

```
#include "main.h"
#include "ai_platform.h"
#include "ai_datatypes_defines.h"
#include "network_1705163992743.h"
#include "network_1705163992743_data.h"
#include "network_1705163992743_data_params.h"
#include "network_1705163992743_config.h"
#include "app_x-cube-ai.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void SystemClock_Config(void);
...
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
...
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }


}
```

and my app_x-cube-ai.c

the MX_UARTx_Init(); is what gives me the error

```
void MX_X_CUBE_AI_Init(void)
{
    MX_UARTx_Init();
    aiValidationInit();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
    /* USER CODE END 5 */
}
```

in bsp_ai.h the reference to MX_USART2_UART_Init in the main

```
#define MX_UARTx_Init MX_USART2_UART_Init
```

Comment: This means you didn't correctly link with the library that defines that function.

Comment: this code is generated when i upload the model when i click ctrl+MX_UARTx_Init it takes me to bsp_ai.h when i click on ctrl+MX_USART2_UART_Init it takes me to the function in the main but still get this error I don't know if it's related to something else like something declared before the other

Comment: The problem is with how you're linking the code. I don't know anything more.

Comment: The problem is that MX_USART2_UART_Init is declared static but you want it global means using it in an other source file (MX_X_CUBE_AI_Init). Remove static and move the declaration in a header file and include it where needed.

Answer (score 2):

You probably changed the file structure of the Cube generated startup and configuration files.

As `static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)` is ***`static`*** it has to be defined in the **same file** (more precisely compilation unit) you call it from.

You call this function from the *`app_x-cube-ai.c`* and define it in *`main.c`* file. It will not work as `MX_USART2_UART_Init` does not have an external linkage.

You can:

1. remove `static` from the function prototype and definition
2. move the definition to the compilation unit (*file*) this function is called from.

Comment: Within STM32CubeMX, on the "Project Manager" tab and the "Advanced Settings" page, you can choose whether `MX_USART2_UART_Init` is generated as a static function or not, i.e. "Visibility".

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @gulpr is technicaly correct, but do not reflect code generator environment of STM32CubeIDE. `MX_USART2_UART_Init` is generated function and it is defined and delclared as static by default which prevents using it outside main.c (where it is placed by default).

To change this beahaviour

1. Open .ioc file in STM32CubeIDE or STM32CubeMX.
2. Go to *Project Manager* tab
3. Go to *Advanced Settings* section
4. In *Generated Function Call* section, uncheck *Visbility (Static)* checbox at the *MX_USART2_UART_Init* line.
5. Save changes and in STM32CubeMX click *GENERATE CODE* button.

[image: STM32 Setting static code visbility]